# Calling applet's method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, applet

I need to print some information via an applet.
My applet from signed qds-client.jar:

```
public class PrintText extends Applet  implements Printable {

 private ClientAccount clientAccount;

 public ClientAccount getClientAccount() {
     return clientAccount;
 }

 public void setClientAccount (ClientAccount clientAccount) {
     this.clientAccount = clientAccount;
 }

 public void setClientAccountFromJSON(String json) {
     this.clientAccount = toClientAccountFromJSON(json);
     System.out.println("------------------------------SetClient");
 }

 public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page) throws
         ...
 }

 public void printText() throws PrinterException {
     ...
 }

 private String getTextToPrint(ClientAccount clientAccount) throws PrinterException {
     ...
 }

 private ClientAccount toClientAccountFromJSON(String json) {
     return JsonUtils.fromJson(ClientAccount.class, json);
 }

 public void startPrint () {
     System.out.println("------------------------------------------Start");
 }
}
```

Accordinng JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5+" codebase="http://localhost:10099/partials/" href="print.jnlp">
    <information>
       ....
    </information>

<resources>
    <jar href="/partials/qds-client.jar"/>
    <jar href="/partials/core-3.2.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="/partials/gson-2.3.1.jar"/>
</resources>

<applet-desc name="printText" main-class="com.qdsrest.utils.printer.PrintText" width="500" height="200"></applet-desc>

<update check="background"/>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

and HTML tag:

```
<applet name="printApplet" jnlp_href="/partials/print.jnlp" width="10" height="10">
<param name="permissions" value="all-permissions"/>
</applet>
```

When I call applet's method from js file like this:

```
document.printApplet.setClientAccountFromJSON({/not empty/});
```

I get

```
Error: Error calling method on NPObject!
```

in Mozilla and

```
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory: try again ..
```

in Java Console and method doesn't work. Why I get "try again .."? What does it mean?
Method toClientAccountFromJSON uses GSON lib gson-2.3.1.jar wich perfectly deserialize JSON object into Java object. What wrong things did I do? Tell me, please, a right thinking way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the current details, but long ago at the age of the first browser wars, there once was an attribute `mayscript` your applet needed in order to talk to javascript.

Oh and parameter needs to be string:

```
 setClientAccountFromJSON("somestring or stringvar");
```

Comment: Whats the change you made? Whats the output?

Comment: First: added attr mayscript="true" to <applet>

Comment: And type that I pass to setClientAccountFromJSON method is String. This is code where I call applet's method document.printApplet.setClientAccountFromJSON(JSON.stringify($scope.clientAccount)); All should be work, but not.